# java console mouselistener

Tags: java, console, mouseevent, mouselistener

I am trying to make a mouse recorder, I cant seem to get a mouse listener to work with a console, is this possable and how would I go about it Thanks.

Comment: What events are you trying to capture in the console?

Comment: the position of the mouse(x,y)

Comment: Is the coordinates of the screen enough, or do you need the console coordinates?

Comment: See the [PointerInfo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/PointerInfo.html) class.

Comment: This requires that you poll the information in that class at intervals, and it wouldn't record clicks.

Comment: damm I need it to record clicks thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you wrote your own console that fired mouse events, I dont' think you're going to be able to do it.  What widget are you going to register your mouselistener against otherwise?  The console isn't a swing component, therefore, no swing events.

Comment: not quite sure what you mean but if i made a swing application which didnt open up a window I could find the co-ordinates of the mouse clicks???

Comment: Well, if you're just looking for mouse x&y coordinates using mouseevents, you're going to need some java.awt.Component subclass (Like a JPanel or a JFrame) in order to call the addMouseMotionListener function.   You could probably create a JFrame and never call setVisible() on it, though I can't remember if it will still fire mouseMoveEvents.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using **global hooks**.
In order to use them you'll need to include some **natives** or try the same using **JNI** (see: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)).

Two examples:

- http://kra.lc/blog/2011/07/java-global-system-hook/
  (works well - I would advice to re-indent the c++ content and if you know how to do, merge it into 1-2 files - your eyes will thank you)
- http://www.jotschi.de/Technik/2008/01/06/java-global-keyboard-hook-jni.html
  (never tried, but looks more simple)

Edit:

- Example for some **playback** functionalities:

  ```
  import java.awt.AWTException;
  import java.awt.DisplayMode;
  import java.awt.MouseInfo;
  import java.awt.PointerInfo;
  import java.awt.Robot;
  import java.util.Random;

  // class instructions

  try {
      PointerInfo pntInfo = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
      DisplayMode dispMode = pntInfo.getDevice().getDisplayMode();
      int newX = new Random().nextInt( dispMode.getWidth() );
      int newY = new Random().nextInt( dispMode.getHeight() );
      new Robot( pntInfo.getDevice() ).mouseMove( newX, newY );
  } catch ( AWTException exception ) {  }
  ```

Sorry for my late answer ;)