# How do I use console to track mouse movement?

Tags: java, mouseevent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java console mouselistener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336112/java-console-mouselistener)

I have to make an interactive word search for my final project, but I don't know how to track mouse movements.

I found `MouseMotionListener`, but I only found examples that use the Swing class, which my teacher specifically told us not to use.

Are there ways to use `MouseMotionListener` with console? If not, how can I track mouse coordinates on the console screen?

Comment: Consoles and mouse input don't mix.

Comment: Nope, but the `javax.swing.*` classes are just convenience clones of the classes from `java.awt.*`. They are almost the same, so I think a look at the docs should be enough. (Just remove the 'J' from a Swing class and you got it's AWT name, most of the time.)